# C# Regular Expression To Match Number at end of a string

Tags: c#

I have a string that ends with _[a number] e.g. _1 _12 etc etc.

I'm looking for a regular expression to pull out this number

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\d+)$
```

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)$", 
            RegexOptions.Compiled | 
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

        Match match = regex.Match("_1_12");

        if (match.Success)
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and for the end of the string (not line) make sure that you don't set the Multiline option.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
_(\d+)$
```